I can't figure out what the problem is when working with bitmex api
I am trying to connect to bitmex and try their user specific endpoints, however even though I have confirmed my API keys are correct and have actually connected to their private areas like Account info and in this case wallet assets, the minute I start adding parameters I get errors.
import requests
import time
import hashlib
import hmac

def get_assets(API_KEY, API_SECRET):
    base_url = 'https://www.bitmex.com'
    path = '/api/v1/user/wallet'  
    url = base_url + path
    b = path + "?currency=DOGE"
    
    expires = int(time.time()) + 5

    verb = 'GET'
    body = ''  # Empty string for GET requests
    message = verb +  b + str(expires) + body

    signature = hmac.new(
        API_SECRET,
        message.encode('utf-8'),
        digestmod=hashlib.sha256
    ).hexdigest()

    headers = {
        'api-key': API_KEY,
        'api-signature': signature,
        'api-expires': str(expires),

    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        return f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}"

get_assets(API_KEY, API_SECRET)

If I remove the currency doge portion this code works without issues, proving that the API key isn't the issue.
But I'll keep getting this error: Error: 401 - {"error":{"message":"Signature not valid.","name":"HTTPError"}}
I have tried every variation of including/excluding the currency pick and trying it at different stages of the encryption process.

url, used in the requests.get() call and b in signature message do not match and that is what error says (otherwise the message would be "Authorization Required"). The value of url right now is just the endpoint 'https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/user/wallet', without the currency (and you don't provide currency param in any other way).
That said you probably want to use b, instead of url or even better use
params = {'currency': 'DOGE'}
response = requests.get('https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/user/wallet', params=params, headers=headers)
# or just  
# response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

